Trigger conditions to start approval process or notify on rejction
I have a SharePoint list with the following columns:

Approval Status
Sign-Off

The scenario is this:
The end-user is assigned a task. The end-user completed the task and right clicks, goes to the automation list item and chooses request sign-off and enters a name. The Sign-Off column changes to 'Pending'
A teams notification is sent to the name entered and that person either approves or rejects the sign-off request. The column changes to either Approved or Rejected.
Here is my ask:
How do I write a trigger condition for an array:
@triggerOutputs()?['body/value']
That watches column 'Sign-Off' for the word Approved, at which point in time the following flow takes place:

Update list item to Pending Approval
Begin approval process
Wait for approval
Upon approval, set approval status
Marks list item as complete.

Otherwise, rejection notification is sent to requestor.
I HAVE:

Built the approval process already.

I CANNOT FIGURE OUT

How to write the expression to begin the approval process once Sign-Off is set to 'Approved'

Can anyone please help? I have been scouring the internet for a week and I just can't find what I am looking for.

I have tried: @equals(triggerOutputs()?['body/Sign-Off/Value, Approved] and @equals(triggerOutputs()?['body/Sign-Off Status/Value], Approved] and @equals(triggerOutputs()?['body/Sign-Off Status/Value], Approved) but powerautomate will not leet me save to test.

In the flow run, click on "Show Output" of the trigger action. Find the field you want to check and see what the structure is. If you have trouble composing a function for that structure, post this output into your question so people can give you advice.

Here is an example of trigger condition which might help construct yours. Please describe your list structure and approval process requirements for further assistance.
@or(
     or(
       or(
          and(equals(triggerBody()?['Level1Approval-CHOICEColumn']?['Value'],'Initiate Review'), equals(triggerBody()?['SendforSign-YESNOColumn'],false)),
          and(equals(triggerBody()?['Level1Approval-CHOICEColumn']?['Value'], 'All Approved'), equals(triggerBody()?['SendforSign-YESNOColumn'], true))
         ), 
      and(equals(triggerBody()?['Level1Approval-CHOICEColumn']?['Value'],'Resubmit'), equals(triggerBody()?['SendforSign-YESNOColumn'],false))
      ), 
   and(equals(triggerBody()?['Level1Approval-CHOICEColumn']?['Value'], 'Resubmit to Secretary'), equals(triggerBody()?['SendforSign-YESNOColumn'], true))
   )


